# Using a button to move images to a different div

Tags: javascript, html

I'm in the process of creating a drag and drop card tracker. The cards are represented by images and can be dragged into different divs that represent the different card piles - e.g. discard pile, draw pile, player hands etc. The divs are overlaid onto a background image so you know where to drag to.

I would like to add a button with a function to send any cards in the discard pile back to their original pile; however, any cards that are removed from the game or in players' hands need to remain in those divs. In other words, in pseudo code something like: "If cards 1-110 are in discard pile then move to draw pile."
But more specifically to the way mine is set up
"If a particular card is in div 31, 32, 33 or 34 then move to the correct div, which would be div 5 - 13 depending on the card."

Sorry this is a more general query than I like to post, but I'm really stuck on this. I've looked a lot on here, W3 Schools etc and while there are lots of things that seem like they should help, I just can't adapt any of the code to my needs without breaking it.

Many thanks for your help in advance!

```
    <style>

body {
    margin: 0;
  }
  
   .container {;
  }

  button{
    background-color: rgb(63, 116, 2);
  }
  
  #div01 {
    position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 50px;
  width: 260px;
  height: 260px;
  margin: 2px;
  padding: 2px;
  }

  
  #div1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  left: 546px;
  width: 260px;
  height: 260px;
  margin: 2px;
  padding: 2px;
  background-color: rgba(105, 211, 211,0);
}
#div2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  left: 812px;
  width: 260px;
  height: 320px;
  margin: 2px;
  padding: 2px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0);
}
#div31 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 250px;
  left: 2px;
  width: 270px;
  height: 356px;
  margin: 2px;
  padding: 2px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 184, 53, 0.);
}
#div32 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 250px;
  left: 272px;
  width: 270px;
  height: 356px;
  margin: 2px;
  padding: 2px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 184, 53, 0.);
}
  #div33 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 250px;
  left: 542px;
  width: 270px;
  height: 356px;
  margin: 2px;
  padding: 2px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 184, 53, 0.);
  }

  #div34 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 250px;
  left: 812px;
  width: 270px;
  height: 356px;
  margin: 2px;
  padding: 2px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 184, 53, 0.);
  }

  #div41 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 606px;
  left: 2px;
  width: 270px;
  height: 356px;
  margin: 2px;
  padding: 2px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 184, 53, 0.);
}
#div42 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 606px;
  left: 272px;
  width: 270px;
  height: 356px;
  margin: 2px;
  padding: 2px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 184, 53, 0.);
}
  #div43 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 606px;
  left: 542px;
  width: 270px;
  height: 356px;
  margin: 2px;
  padding: 2px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 184, 53, 0.);
  }

  #div44 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 606px;
  left: 812px;
  width: 270px;
  height: 356px;
  margin: 2px;
  padding: 2px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 184, 53, 0.);
  }

#div5 {
position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  left: 1078px;
  width: 260px;
  height: 330px;
  margin: 2px;
  padding: 2px;
  background-color: rgb(105, 211, 211, 0);
}
  
#div6 {
position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  left: 1342px;
  width: 260px;
  height: 330px;
  margin: 2px;
  padding: 2px;
  background-color: rgba(51, 51, 56, 0);
}
  
#div7 {
position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  left: 1608px;
  width: 260px;
  height: 330px;
  margin: 2px;
  padding: 2px;
  background-color: rgba(167, 32, 32, 0);

}
#div8 {
position: absolute;
  top: 325px;
  left: 1078px;
  width: 260px;
  height: 396px;
  margin: 2px;
  padding: 2px;
  background-color: rgb(105, 211, 211, 0);
}
  
#div9 {
position: absolute;
  top: 325px;
  left: 1342px;
  width: 260px;
  height: 396px;
  margin: 2px;
  padding: 2px;
  background-color: rgba(51, 51, 56, 0);
}
  
#div10 {
position: absolute;
  top: 325px;
  left: 1608px;
  width: 260px;
  height: 396px;
  margin: 2px;
  padding: 2px;
  background-color: rgba(167, 32, 32, 0);

}
#div11 {
position: absolute;
  top: 708px;
  left: 1078px;
  width: 260px;
  height: 220px;
  margin: 2px;
  padding: 2px;
  background-color: rgb(105, 211, 211, 0);
}
  
#div12 {
position: absolute;
  top: 708px;
  left: 1342px;
  width: 260px;
  height: 220px;
  margin: 2px;
  padding: 2px;
  background-color: rgba(51, 51, 56, 0);
}
  
#div13 {
position: absolute;
  top: 708px;
  left: 1608px;
  width: 260px;
  height: 220px;
  margin: 2px;
  padding: 2px;
  background-color: rgba(167, 32, 32, 0);

}

  .draggable {
    padding: 0px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    cursor: move;
    padding: 1px;
  }
  
  .draggable.dragging {
    opacity: .1;
  }

</style>

<img src="C:\Users\User\Desktop\TS_HTML_card_counter\backgrounds\full background.jpg" draggable="false" width="1874" height="923" top="0px" left="0px" >

<div class="container" id="div01">
    <button type="button" background-color="#008CBA" onclick="reshuffle()">Reshuffle</button>
</div>



<div class="container" id="div1">
       
  </div>
  <div class="container" id="div2">
      <div id="cd6"> <img src="C:\Users\User\Desktop\TS_HTML_card_counter\cards\6_china_card.jpg" class="draggable" draggable="true" width="258" height="18"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="container" id="div31">
  
  </div>
  <div class="container" id="div32">

  </div>
  <div class="container" id="div33">

  </div>
  <div class="container" id="div34">

  </div>
  <div class="container" id="div41">

  </div>
  <div class="container" id="div42">

  </div>
  <div class="container" id="div43">

  </div>
  <div class="container" id="div44">

  </div>

  <div class="container" id="div5">
    
    <img id="cd4" img src="C:\Users\User\Desktop\TS_HTML_card_counter\cards\4_duck_and_cover.jpg" class="draggable" draggable="true" width="258" height="18">
    <img src="C:\Users\User\Desktop\TS_HTML_card_counter\cards\5_five_year_plan.jpg" class="draggable" draggable="true" width="258" height="18">
    <img src="C:\Users\User\Desktop\TS_HTML_card_counter\cards\4_duck_and_cover.jpg" class="draggable" draggable="true" width="258" height="18">
    <img src="C:\Users\User\Desktop\TS_HTML_card_counter\cards\5_five_year_plan.jpg" class="draggable" draggable="true" width="258" height="18">
    <img src="C:\Users\User\Desktop\TS_HTML_card_counter\cards\4_duck_and_cover.jpg" class="draggable" draggable="true" width="258" height="18">
    <img src="C:\Users\User\Desktop\TS_HTML_card_counter\cards\5_five_year_plan.jpg" class="draggable" draggable="true" width="258" height="18">
    <img src="C:\Users\User\Desktop\TS_HTML_card_counter\cards\4_duck_and_cover.jpg" class="draggable" draggable="true" width="258" height="18">
    <img src="C:\Users\User\Desktop\TS_HTML_card_counter\cards\5_five_year_plan.jpg" class="draggable" draggable="true" width="258" height="18">
    <img src="C:\Users\User\Desktop\TS_HTML_card_counter\cards\4_duck_and_cover.jpg" class="draggable" draggable="true" width="258" height="18">
    <img src="C:\Users\User\Desktop\TS_HTML_card_counter\cards\5_five_year_plan.jpg" class="draggable" draggable="true" width="258" height="18">
    <img src="C:\Users\User\Desktop\TS_HTML_card_counter\cards\4_duck_and_cover.jpg" class="draggable" draggable="true" width="258" height="18">
    <img src="C:\Users\User\Desktop\TS_HTML_card_counter\cards\5_five_year_plan.jpg" class="draggable" draggable="true" width="258" height="18">
    <img src="C:\Users\User\Desktop\TS_HTML_card_counter\cards\4_duck_and_cover.jpg" class="draggable" draggable="true" width="258" height="18">
    <img src="C:\Users\User\Desktop\TS_HTML_card_counter\cards\5_five_year_plan.jpg" class="draggable" draggable="true" width="258" height="18">
   </div>

  <div class="container" id="div6">
    <img src="C:\Users\User\Desktop\TS_HTML_card_counter\cards\1_Asia_scoring.jpg" class="draggable" draggable="true" width="258" height="18">
    <img src="C:\Users\User\Desktop\TS_HTML_card_counter\cards\2_Europe_scoring.jpg" class="draggable" draggable="true" width="258" height="18">
    <img src="C:\Users\User\Desktop\TS_HTML_card_counter\cards\3_Middle_east_scoring.jpg" class="draggable" draggable="true" width="258" height="18">
    <img src="C:\Users\User\Desktop\TS_HTML_card_counter\cards\1_Asia_scoring.jpg" class="draggable" draggable="true" width="258" height="18">
    <img src="C:\Users\User\Desktop\TS_HTML_card_counter\cards\2_Europe_scoring.jpg" class="draggable" draggable="true" width="258" height="18">
    <img src="C:\Users\User\Desktop\TS_HTML_card_counter\cards\3_Middle_east_scoring.jpg" class="draggable" draggable="true" width="258" height="18">
    <img src="C:\Users\User\Desktop\TS_HTML_card_counter\cards\1_Asia_scoring.jpg" class="draggable" draggable="true" width="258" height="18">
    <img src="C:\Users\User\Desktop\TS_HTML_card_counter\cards\2_Europe_scoring.jpg" class="draggable" draggable="true" width="258" height="18">
    <img src="C:\Users\User\Desktop\TS_HTML_card_counter\cards\3_Middle_east_scoring.jpg" class="draggable" draggable="true" width="258" height="18">
  </div>

  <div class="container" id="div7">
    <img src="C:\Users\User\Desktop\TS_HTML_card_counter\cards\10_blockade.jpg" class="draggable" draggable="true" width="258" height="18">
    <img src="C:\Users\User\Desktop\TS_HTML_card_counter\cards\8_fidel.jpg" class="draggable" draggable="true" width="258" height="18">
    <img src="C:\Users\User\Desktop\TS_HTML_card_counter\cards\9_vietnam_revolts.jpg" class="draggable" draggable="true" width="258" height="18">
    <img src="C:\Users\User\Desktop\TS_HTML_card_counter\cards\7_socialist_governments.jpg" class="draggable" draggable="true" width="258" height="18">
    <img src="C:\Users\User\Desktop\TS_HTML_card_counter\cards\7_socialist_governments.jpg" class="draggable" draggable="true" width="258" height="18">
    <img src="C:\Users\User\Desktop\TS_HTML_card_counter\cards\8_fidel.jpg" class="draggable" draggable="true" width="258" height="18">
    <img src="C:\Users\User\Desktop\TS_HTML_card_counter\cards\9_vietnam_revolts.jpg" class="draggable" draggable="true" width="258" height="18">
    <img src="C:\Users\User\Desktop\TS_HTML_card_counter\cards\10_blockade.jpg" class="draggable" draggable="true" width="258" height="18">
    <img src="C:\Users\User\Desktop\TS_HTML_card_counter\cards\9_vietnam_revolts.jpg" class="draggable" draggable="true" width="258" height="18">
    <img src="C:\Users\User\Desktop\TS_HTML_card_counter\cards\10_blockade.jpg" class="draggable" draggable="true" width="258" height="18">
    <img src="C:\Users\User\Desktop\TS_HTML_card_counter\cards\7_socialist_governments.jpg" class="draggable" draggable="true" width="258" height="18">
    <img src="C:\Users\User\Desktop\TS_HTML_card_counter\cards\8_fidel.jpg" class="draggable" draggable="true" width="258" height="18">
    <img src="C:\Users\User\Desktop\TS_HTML_card_counter\cards\9_vietnam_revolts.jpg" class="draggable" draggable="true" width="258" height="18">
    <img src="C:\Users\User\Desktop\TS_HTML_card_counter\cards\10_blockade.jpg" class="draggable" draggable="true" width="258" height="18">
    <img src="C:\Users\User\Desktop\TS_HTML_card_counter\cards\10_blockade.jpg" class="draggable" draggable="true" width="258" height="18">
  </div>

  <div class="container" id="div8">
    <img src="C:\Users\User\Desktop\TS_HTML_card_counter\cards\4_duck_and_cover.jpg" class="draggable" draggable="true" width="258" height="18">
    <img src="C:\Users\User\Desktop\TS_HTML_card_counter\cards\5_five_year_plan.jpg" class="draggable" draggable="true" width="258" height="18">
    <img src="C:\Users\User\Desktop\TS_HTML_card_counter\cards\4_duck_and_cover.jpg" class="draggable" draggable="true" width="258" height="18">
    <img src="C:\Users\User\Desktop\TS_HTML_card_counter\cards\5_five_year_plan.jpg" class="draggable" draggable="true" width="258" height="18">
    <img src="C:\Users\User\Desktop\TS_HTML_card_counter\cards\4_duck_and_cover.jpg" class="draggable" draggable="true" width="258" height="18">
    <img src="C:\Users\User\Desktop\TS_HTML_card_counter\cards\5_five_year_plan.jpg" class="draggable" draggable="true" width="258" height="18">
    <img src="C:\Users\User\Desktop\TS_HTML_card_counter\cards\4_duck_and_cover.jpg" class="draggable" draggable="true" width="258" height="18">
    <img src="C:\Users\User\Desktop\TS_HTML_card_counter\cards\5_five_year_plan.jpg" class="draggable" draggable="true" width="258" height="18">
    <img src="C:\Users\User\Desktop\TS_HTML_card_counter\cards\4_duck_and_cover.jpg" class="draggable" draggable="true" width="258" height="18">
    <img src="C:\Users\User\Desktop\TS_HTML_card_counter\cards\5_five_year_plan.jpg" class="draggable" draggable="true" width="258" height="18">
    <img src="C:\Users\User\Desktop\TS_HTML_card_counter\cards\4_duck_and_cover.jpg" class="draggable" draggable="true" width="258" height="18">
    <img src="C:\Users\User\Desktop\TS_HTML_card_counter\cards\5_five_year_plan.jpg" class="draggable" draggable="true" width="258" height="18">
    <img src="C:\Users\User\Desktop\TS_HTML_card_counter\cards\4_duck_and_cover.jpg" class="draggable" draggable="true" width="258" height="18">
    <img src="C:\Users\User\Desktop\TS_HTML_card_counter\cards\5_five_year_plan.jpg" class="draggable" draggable="true" width="258" height="18">
    <img src="C:\Users\User\Desktop\TS_HTML_card_counter\cards\5_five_year_plan.jpg" class="draggable" draggable="true" width="258" height="18">
    <img src="C:\Users\User\Desktop\TS_HTML_card_counter\cards\4_duck_and_cover.jpg" class="draggable" draggable="true" width="258" height="18">
    <img src="C:\Users\User\Desktop\TS_HTML_card_counter\cards\5_five_year_plan.jpg" class="draggable" draggable="true" width="258" height="18">
    <img src="C:\Users\User\Desktop\TS_HTML_card_counter\cards\5_five_year_plan.jpg" class="draggable" draggable="true" width="258" height="18">
  </div>

  <div class="container" id="div9">
    <img src="C:\Users\User\Desktop\TS_HTML_card_counter\cards\38_southeast_asia_scoring.jpg" class="draggable" draggable="true" width="258" height="18">
    <img src="C:\Users\User\Desktop\TS_HTML_card_counter\cards\37_central_america_scoring.jpg" class="draggable" draggable="true" width="258" height="18">
    <img src="C:\Users\User\Desktop\TS_HTML_card_counter\cards\79_Africa_scoring.jpg" class="draggable" draggable="true" width="258" height="18">
    <img src="C:\Users\User\Desktop\TS_HTML_card_counter\cards\81_South_America_scoring.jpg" class="draggable" draggable="true" width="258" height="18">
    <img src="C:\Users\User\Desktop\TS_HTML_card_counter\cards\2_Europe_scoring.jpg" class="draggable" draggable="true" width="258" height="18">
    <img src="C:\Users\User\Desktop\TS_HTML_card_counter\cards\3_Middle_east_scoring.jpg" class="draggable" draggable="true" width="258" height="18">
    <img src="C:\Users\User\Desktop\TS_HTML_card_counter\cards\1_Asia_scoring.jpg" class="draggable" draggable="true" width="258" height="18">
    <img src="C:\Users\User\Desktop\TS_HTML_card_counter\cards\2_Europe_scoring.jpg" class="draggable" draggable="true" width="258" height="18">
    <img src="C:\Users\User\Desktop\TS_HTML_card_counter\cards\3_Middle_east_scoring.jpg" class="draggable" draggable="true" width="258" height="18">
    <img src="C:\Users\User\Desktop\TS_HTML_card_counter\cards\1_Asia_scoring.jpg" class="draggable" draggable="true" width="258" height="18">
    <img src="C:\Users\User\Desktop\TS_HTML_card_counter\cards\2_Europe_scoring.jpg" class="draggable" draggable="true" width="258" height="18">
    <img src="C:\Users\User\Desktop\TS_HTML_card_counter\cards\3_Middle_east_scoring.jpg" class="draggable" draggable="true" width="258" height="18">
    <img src="C:\Users\User\Desktop\TS_HTML_card_counter\cards\1_Asia_scoring.jpg" class="draggable" draggable="true" width="258" height="18">
    <img src="C:\Users\User\Desktop\TS_HTML_card_counter\cards\2_Europe_scoring.jpg" class="draggable" draggable="true" width="258" height="18">
    <img src="C:\Users\User\Desktop\TS_HTML_card_counter\cards\3_Middle_east_scoring.jpg" class="draggable" draggable="true" width="258" height="18">
  </div>

  <div class="container" id="div10">
    <img src="C:\Users\User\Desktop\TS_HTML_card_counter\cards\7_socialist_governments.jpg" class="draggable" draggable="true" width="258" height="18">
    <img src="C:\Users\User\Desktop\TS_HTML_card_counter\cards\8_fidel.jpg" class="draggable" draggable="true" width="258" height="18">
    <img src="C:\Users\User\Desktop\TS_HTML_card_counter\cards\9_vietnam_revolts.jpg" class="draggable" draggable="true" width="258" height="18">
    <img src="C:\Users\User\Desktop\TS_HTML_card_counter\cards\10_blockade.jpg" class="draggable" draggable="true" width="258" height="18">
    <img src="C:\Users\User\Desktop\TS_HTML_card_counter\cards\7_socialist_governments.jpg" class="draggable" draggable="true" width="258" height="18">
    <img src="C:\Users\User\Desktop\TS_HTML_card_counter\cards\8_fidel.jpg" class="draggable" draggable="true" width="258" height="18">
    <img src="C:\Users\User\Desktop\TS_HTML_card_counter\cards\9_vietnam_revolts.jpg" class="draggable" draggable="true" width="258" height="18">
    <img src="C:\Users\User\Desktop\TS_HTML_card_counter\cards\10_blockade.jpg" class="draggable" draggable="true" width="258" height="18">
    <img src="C:\Users\User\Desktop\TS_HTML_card_counter\cards\9_vietnam_revolts.jpg" class="draggable" draggable="true" width="258" height="18">
    <img src="C:\Users\User\Desktop\TS_HTML_card_counter\cards\10_blockade.jpg" class="draggable" draggable="true" width="258" height="18">
    <img src="C:\Users\User\Desktop\TS_HTML_card_counter\cards\7_socialist_governments.jpg" class="draggable" draggable="true" width="258" height="18">
    <img src="C:\Users\User\Desktop\TS_HTML_card_counter\cards\8_fidel.jpg" class="draggable" draggable="true" width="258" height="18">
    <img src="C:\Users\User\Desktop\TS_HTML_card_counter\cards\9_vietnam_revolts.jpg" class="draggable" draggable="true" width="258" height="18">
    <img src="C:\Users\User\Desktop\TS_HTML_card_counter\cards\10_blockade.jpg" class="draggable" draggable="true" width="258" height="18">
    <img src="C:\Users\User\Desktop\TS_HTML_card_counter\cards\10_blockade.jpg" class="draggable" draggable="true" width="258" height="18">
  </div>

  <div class="container" id="div11">
    <img src="C:\Users\User\Desktop\TS_HTML_card_counter\cards\4_duck_and_cover.jpg" class="draggable" draggable="true" width="258" height="18">
    <img src="C:\Users\User\Desktop\TS_HTML_card_counter\cards\5_five_year_plan.jpg" class="draggable" draggable="true" width="258" height="18">
    <img src="C:\Users\User\Desktop\TS_HTML_card_counter\cards\4_duck_and_cover.jpg" class="draggable" draggable="true" width="258" height="18">
    <img src="C:\Users\User\Desktop\TS_HTML_card_counter\cards\5_five_year_plan.jpg" class="draggable" draggable="true" width="258" height="18">
    <img src="C:\Users\User\Desktop\TS_HTML_card_counter\cards\4_duck_and_cover.jpg" class="draggable" draggable="true" width="258" height="18">
    <img src="C:\Users\User\Desktop\TS_HTML_card_counter\cards\5_five_year_plan.jpg" class="draggable" draggable="true" width="258" height="18">
    <img src="C:\Users\User\Desktop\TS_HTML_card_counter\cards\4_duck_and_cover.jpg" class="draggable" draggable="true" width="258" height="18">
    <img src="C:\Users\User\Desktop\TS_HTML_card_counter\cards\5_five_year_plan.jpg" class="draggable" draggable="true" width="258" height="18">
    <img src="C:\Users\User\Desktop\TS_HTML_card_counter\cards\4_duck_and_cover.jpg" class="draggable" draggable="true" width="258" height="18">
    <img src="C:\Users\User\Desktop\TS_HTML_card_counter\cards\5_five_year_plan.jpg" class="draggable" draggable="true" width="258" height="18">
  </div>

  <div class="container" id="div12">
    <img src="C:\Users\User\Desktop\TS_HTML_card_counter\cards\1_Asia_scoring.jpg" class="draggable" draggable="true" width="258" height="18">
    <img src="C:\Users\User\Desktop\TS_HTML_card_counter\cards\2_Europe_scoring.jpg" class="draggable" draggable="true" width="258" height="18">
    <img src="C:\Users\User\Desktop\TS_HTML_card_counter\cards\3_Middle_east_scoring.jpg" class="draggable" draggable="true" width="258" height="18">
  </div>

  <div class="container" id="div13">
    <img src="C:\Users\User\Desktop\TS_HTML_card_counter\cards\7_socialist_governments.jpg" class="draggable" draggable="true" width="258" height="18">
    <img src="C:\Users\User\Desktop\TS_HTML_card_counter\cards\8_fidel.jpg" class="draggable" draggable="true" width="258" height="18">
    <img src="C:\Users\User\Desktop\TS_HTML_card_counter\cards\9_vietnam_revolts.jpg" class="draggable" draggable="true" width="258" height="18">
    <img src="C:\Users\User\Desktop\TS_HTML_card_counter\cards\10_blockade.jpg" class="draggable" draggable="true" width="258" height="18">
    <img src="C:\Users\User\Desktop\TS_HTML_card_counter\cards\7_socialist_governments.jpg" class="draggable" draggable="true" width="258" height="18">
    <img src="C:\Users\User\Desktop\TS_HTML_card_counter\cards\8_fidel.jpg" class="draggable" draggable="true" width="258" height="18">
    <img src="C:\Users\User\Desktop\TS_HTML_card_counter\cards\9_vietnam_revolts.jpg" class="draggable" draggable="true" width="258" height="18">
    <img src="C:\Users\User\Desktop\TS_HTML_card_counter\cards\10_blockade.jpg" class="draggable" draggable="true" width="258" height="18">
    <img src="C:\Users\User\Desktop\TS_HTML_card_counter\cards\9_vietnam_revolts.jpg" class="draggable" draggable="true" width="258" height="18">
    <img src="C:\Users\User\Desktop\TS_HTML_card_counter\cards\10_blockade.jpg" class="draggable" draggable="true" width="258" height="18">
  </div>

  <script>
  const draggables = document.querySelectorAll('.draggable')
    const containers = document.querySelectorAll('.container')
    
    draggables.forEach(draggable => {
      draggable.addEventListener('dragstart', () => {
        draggable.classList.add('dragging')
      })
    
      draggable.addEventListener('dragend', () => {
        draggable.classList.remove('dragging')
      })
    })
    
    containers.forEach(container => {
      container.addEventListener('dragover', e => {
        e.preventDefault()
        const afterElement = getDragAfterElement(container, e.clientY)
        const draggable = document.querySelector('.dragging')
        if (afterElement == null) {
          container.appendChild(draggable)
        } else {
          container.insertBefore(draggable, afterElement)
        }
      })
    })
    
    function getDragAfterElement(container, y) {
      const draggableElements = [...container.querySelectorAll('.draggable:not(.dragging)')]
    
      return draggableElements.reduce((closest, child) => {
        const box = child.getBoundingClientRect()
        const offset = y - box.top - box.height / 2
        if (offset < 0 && offset > closest.offset) {
          return { offset: offset, element: child }
        } else {
          return closest
        }
      }, { offset: Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY }).element
    }
 

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a library to do something like this rather than code it myself.

One such library is [Muuri](https://muuri.dev/). I have used it to do a Kanban board before, but there are lots of examples you can look at on their website.

Comment: Thanks. I'll take a look.